# Fragment ui is not retained when using FragmentTransaction.attach() and detach()

Tags: android, android-fragments, detach

From what I understand of the documentation, you can detach a fragment and reattach it later and it will automatically look the same as when it was detached. Is there more to it than that? I have a simple action bar with 2 buttons for 2 different fragments. When I switch from the first to the second back to the first, the image that was loaded in the first fragment is longer visible. Am I using attach/detach incorrectly or do I need to manage the instanceState myself and redraw the ui. If so, what's the point of the attach and detach methods?

```
   @Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();    
    ndi=new NasaDailyFragment(this);
    bnf=new BreakingNewsFragment(this);
   ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   ft.add(R.id.focused_view_container,ndi).commit();

}

public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction f) {

switch(tab.getPosition()){
case 0:
    ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    if(!ndi.isAdded()){ 
        ft.replace(R.id.focused_view_container, ndi).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).commit();
        ft.attach(ndi);
        getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }

    break;
case 1:
        ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.detach(ndi);
        ft.replace(R.id.focused_view_container, bnf).commit();
        getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
     break;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Use show and hide instead of attach and detach. Here is a sample code,

```
 private class MyTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        switch (tab.getPosition()) {
        case 0:

            if (frag1 == null) {
                // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
                frag1 = Fragment.instantiate(getApplicationContext(),
                        FeedsActivity.class.getName());
                ft.add(android.R.id.content, frag1, "Feeds");
            } else {
                // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
                ft.show(frag1);
            }
            return;

        case 1:
            if (frag2 == null) {
                // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
                frag2 = Fragment.instantiate(getApplicationContext(),
                        ProfileActivity.class.getName());
                ft.add(android.R.id.content, frag2, "Profile");
            } else {
                // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
                ft.show(frag2);
            }
            return;
        case 2:

            if (frag3 == null) {
                // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
                frag3 = Fragment.instantiate(getApplicationContext(),
                        History.class.getName());
                ft.add(android.R.id.content, frag3, "History");
            } else {
                // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
                ft.show(frag3);
            }

            return;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (frag1 != null) {
            // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
            switch (tab.getPosition()) {
            case 0:
                ft.hide(frag1);
                return;
            case 1:
                ft.hide(frag2);
                return;
            case 2:
                ft.hide(frag3);
                return;

            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, what are attach and detach for?

Comment: @BasimSherif this doesn't work for me. I am using ActionBarSherlock.

Comment: @BasimSherif What is `frag1` you are referring to?

Comment: @BasimSherif, not correct - on detach/attach fragment did not get destroyed, only on remove or replace, thats the whole point of detach/atach.

Answer (score 0):

there is something wrong with you logic - you replace fragment and then again attach it or in case 1 detach and then replace, that is redundant. Beside by with replacing you destroy old fragment every time switching tabs.
I would rather go this way:

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction f) {
    switch(tab.getPosition()){
    case 0:
        if(ndi.isAdded()){ 
            f.detach(bnf);
            f.attach(ndi);
        }else{
            f.add(R.id.focused_view_container, ndi).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        }
    break;
    case 1:
        if(bnf.isAdded()){ 
            f.detach(ndi);
            f.attach(bnf);
        }else{
            f.add(R.id.focused_view_container, bnf).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        }
     break;
}
```

And you do not must call commit on passed FragmentTransaction OnTabSelected event.

Answer (score -1):

By default, the `Fragment` gets recreated when you detach and then attach it. You can change this behavior by calling `setRetainInstance(true)` on the `Fragment`: the actual instance will be held in memory and won't be recreated after detach-attach cycle. But the UI of the `Fragment` is destroyed in both ways and recreated after that, so you need to make sure you populate your views with proper data after reattaching the `Fragment` to the `Activity`. Hope this helps.

Comment: wrong, [setRetainInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29) method is doing other things

Comment: @kreker, "Control whether a fragment instance is retained across Activity re-creation" - does the sense differ?

Comment: yes, the question was about fragment state between attach - detach, not across Activity re-creation